# Changing startup form in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2010 express but i wonder how can i change startup form when the program runs as i have multiple form within my application. I thought of doing so but i figured out that every form i am creating uses the same namespace. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Look in `Program.cs` in the `Main` function for something like this

```
Application.Run(new MyForm());
```

Change `MyForm` to your other form.

Comment: thanx, it works fine now!! Every form i create takes the name of the project as a namespace, can i define a namespace for each form? Is there any advantage of using single namespace?

Comment: You can, but its just adding noise if you do. I would recommend a `Forms` namespace.