# How to set form2 as default?

Tags: c#, forms, default

i want to set form2 as default.
My program starts with Form1.cs and i want that he going start with form2.cs
This is form1, what i have to do ?

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     MessageBox.Show("Form1");
    }
```

And this is Form2

```
public partial class settings : Form
{
    public settings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("'Reported'");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Look at your Program.cs file. You will find the Application.Run(new Form1()) line inside the Main method.

Comment: change the Form1() in the Application.Run into your desired form to start

Comment: maybe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433744/changing-startup-form-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Program.cs` file of your application, modify the starting point (`Main` method) like this :

Step 1:

[image: Step 1]

Step 2:

[image: Step 2]

Answer (score 0):

This can be a little troublesome for a beginner to figure out, the starting point of your application is the Main() method in the Program.cs file, if you open it you will see something like this:

```
 static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
```

All you have to do is to change **Form1** with your starting form.

Comment: Thanks, it works too :>