# How to change the startup form in a project?

Tags: c#, winforms, startup

I made a test project and added in a couple files.

Now I want the startup file to be say `form2.cs` and not `form1.cs`.

I'm having a devil of a time finding the setting that tells the project which file to load 1st when being executed.

Can someone point it out to me please?

Comment: i guess we need to be mind readers to know what type of app this is...please tell us

Comment: @JohnB i'm a gambling man

Comment: @stackoverflow_user What John is trying to say is that you might have wanted to include the `[winforms]` tag so that it's clear what UI technology the question relates to.

Answer (score 7):

## WinForms

in your `Program.cs`, which will look something like this

```
static class Program
{
   /// <summary>
   /// The main entry point for the application.
   /// </summary>
   [STAThread]
   static void Main()
   {
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      Application.Run(new Form1());
   }
}
```

Change

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

To

```
Application.Run(new Form2());
```

---

## WPF

To change startup window update `App.xaml` by changing `Application.StartupUri`

[Application.StartupUri Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.startupuri?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Gets or sets a UI that is automatically shown when an application
>   starts

Remarks

> Typically, you set the `StartupUri` property declaratively in *XAML*.
>   However, you can set `StartupUri` programmatically, such as from a
>   Startup event handler, which is useful if for applications that can
>   only load the necessary UI resources at run time. For example, an
>   application might wait until run time to load its resources if the
>   name of the UI resource is stored in a configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for way of changing startup form.

As stated here: [Changing startup form in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433744/changing-startup-form-in-c-sharp)

> Look in Program.cs in the Main function for something like this
>
> `Application.Run(new MyForm());` Change MyForm to your other form.

Comment: My title was changed as my old title clearly stated C# / VB 2017 in it but someone decided it shouldn't be there....   Wish you guys would stop touching my titles...

Comment: @stackoverflow_user Well, I did not do that. But this solution is up-to date with c# 2017 as well.

Comment: I do not have a program.cs.  This is a Windows Form Program project that I made in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: @stackoverflow_user Can you provide me screen what your solution contains? You have to have something like it there.

Comment: @stackoverflow_user Wierd, I dont see that. You must have it somewhere :D

Comment: I will copy the file from a new blank project to see what happens.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I saw a xaml file so I assume that thi is a WPF app. In that case you need to change this in App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

Change StartupUri to the one that you want.

I hope this will help.