# C# form opens without login

Tags: c#

I created Form 1 as my main form and Form 2 as login form in c# . So while running the applicaition my main form is executing at first without login. And as my Main form coding is done completely I cannot change the sequence of forms. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: change the startup uri of your form  in app.xaml

Comment: In the project properties there is a startup form. Or there is a StartupUri in App.xaml for WPF.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing startup form in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433744/changing-startup-form-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You should mention what tech you are using. Winforms? WPF? WebForms?

Comment: Further details about the question is required. Please include the technologies you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the thing: there's something wrong with your code, and you need to fix it. That means, ultimately, that your assumption that your main form coding is complete is incorrect. *Something's* got to change to sort this out.

Login forms are particularly annoying, because a "startup form" is the host for the application. If you set the startup form to the login form, closing it will close your application. So you basically have two options:

1. Write a custom main method that starts the login form, extracts out the login information and passes the session to your main form. (So there's no longer a startup form at all.) This is the "right" thing to do.
2. Mess with the main form's loading so that when it first displays it displays the login form as a modal form, disabling the main form until the login form is finished. This is relatively easy to do, but will be an absolute mess with many potential bugs.